# Hash collision in Hashmap

Tags: java

I need a simple scenario to produce a hashing collision in a HashMap. Could someone please provide one.

Is it possible to produce hashing collision if my hashmap keys are immutable?

Regards,

Raju komaturi

Comment: Why downvoting for this question,Can anyone explain this precisely.

Comment: I'm guessing because you're asking for something without showing that you've put in an ounce of effort first to solve this yourself.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels:This is what i never faced in my java coding.So i just wanted to learn here.

Comment: This information is well documented online and easily found in a Google search. Why not first look this up and try to learn what you can from the sources available? Then come here if anything confuses you. I would postulate that most of the folks who volunteer here taught themselves most of what they know, and as expected, most here hold the characteristics of self-effort and initiative in high regard, and it is for this reason they dinged you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own type and create a bad hash function:

```
public class BadHash {

    private String aString;

    public BadHash(String s) {
        aString = s;
    }

    public int hashCode() { 
        return aString.length();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // boilerplate stuff
        BadHash obj = (BadHash) other;
        return obj.aString.equals(aString);
    }
}
```

This will make it easy to create a collision.

An example would be:

```
BadHash a = new BadHash("a", value1);
BadHash b = new BadHash("b", value2);
hashMap.add(a);
hashMap.add(b);
```

These two entries would collide because `a` and `b` hash to the same value even though they are not equal.

Comment: +1 This isn't as "obviously wrong" as my answer and nicely demonstrates why you should always implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` in pairs.

Comment: @jinguy:Please explain your answer.

Comment: @KublaiKhan Thanks.  True, but I wanted to create an example where it wouldn't always collide.

Comment: @Raju Komaturi - He gave you what you asked for. *Please explain your question.*

Comment: @Kublai Khan : Question is straightforward,Please refer Jinguy answer.That is what i am expecting.

Comment: jinguy: I understand your answer.Thanks.Is it possible to create hash colission with Immutable keys?

Comment: @RajuKomaturi yes it is possible.  In fact, in my example the keys are immutable.

Comment: @RajuKomaturi - Whether or not they are immutable has no effect, it's solely the data used to construct the hash that determines whether or not they collide.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can change the key class's hash code method.

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 1; // Or any constant value
}
```

This will make every single key collide.

Answer (score 0):

Can't get much simpler than this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("a", null);
map.put("a", null);
```

Comment: That is not a good example.  Because the keys are equal, the second put should be ignored.

Comment: This demonstrates all out key collision, rather than hash collision between two unequal keys (I think this is what the OP is asking for - question isn't clear).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set the `initialCapacity` of the HashMap to a low value and start inserting elements.

I suppose you could also design a class such that two objects can return the same `hashCode` value even though `equals` would return false.

From what I can see though, there's no way with the default HashMap to get it to *tell* you if there's a collision.